# Database records have been purged. Should I shrink? SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, shrink

The developers have purged a lot of data from a database and do not expect the database to ever grow to this size ever again. They are asking me to shrink the data files but since I know this is generally bad practice, due to potential performance issues, would it still be a bad idea in this case?

Thank you :)

Comment: Generally, yes, you're right; shrinking is bad. If you have any Indexes on the database, they're liking to get fragmented; thus you'll end up having to rebuild them. (The whole thing isn't quite that simple, but that's just one reason). Are you going to be gaining a lot of free space from the shrink?

Comment: Yes, developers have stated about 50% of the database

Comment: 50% of what? 100 MB? Don't bother. 50TB? Well, certainly a consideration then. But, also, do you *need* that free space?

Comment: Sorry you are right. 50% of 2TB. Yes, unfortunately the space is needed. I'm still worried about the cost of executing this shrink.

Comment: If you reply as an answer I'll select your answer and close the question :) Thanks btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as an answer, as requested:

Generally, yes, you're right; shrinking is bad. If you have any Indexes on the database, they're liking to get fragmented; thus you'll end up having to rebuild them. (The whole thing isn't quite that simple, but that's just one reason).

If you're going to gain a lot of space when shrinking, and the database is unlikely to change, then it is (possibly) worth a consideration. Note, however, you're going to need to rebuild **all** of your indexes on that database. That's going to then use up more space, which will then end up as "free". I don't recommend then shrinking it again, as then you're back at stage B (fragmented indexes).

In the end, just be careful. Shrinking isn't normally a good idea, unless you really are in dire need to the regained storage space.